# Jasper Reports: How can i have multiple growing subreports in a report?

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

My Requirement is to show two sub reports in a Report. What I am doing is, I have created two sub-reports and put that into a report.

But the issue is that, both the sub reports are growing (i.e. their height is not static as the number of records are variable). I just want the second sub=report to appear after the end of first sub-report. How can I achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the second subreport inside the first subreport, in the page footer. The footer moves down when the detail band grows, so the subreport should always end up underneath the content of the first subreport.

Cheers,

Alexander

Comment: Thanks, but the second subreport is also growing. Also, I have something (totals) to display below the two reports, which I am already displaying in footer. The solution you suggested may not work there.

Comment: Put the total in the footer on the main page. So you have:

Detail: Subreport A
Footer: Totals

Subreport A Detail: Regular stuff.
Subreport A Footer: Subreport B.

Comment: why is this selected as correct answer? the answer given by @Raveendra Mutyala should be selected right.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the option "Position Type" by selecting "Float" as the value. So based on the first reports size the second one will be adjusted.

Regards,
Raveendra Mutyala

Answer (score 1):

Try to add detail band as many as your subreport to your main report (You can right click the detail band and choose "Add another detail band"). And place each subreport on every detail band that you make.
Detail band have ability to shrink and grow depend on your data row and it will fit nicely to your report.

Comment: This tends to work better than the other proposed answers if your report design allows for it. Upvoted.